# How do I jump to after the next match in VIM?

Tags: vim

I've got a file I am working on where I need to make a lot of edits. The text just prior to what I need to edit is constant, but what I need to edit varies. What I'm doing right now is
`/my_constant_text` and `n` to jump to the lines I need to edit. But using `n` like this I still have to move the cursor forward past my matched text to get to where I want to start editing. It seems to me there has to be a way to just my cursor to just past my matched text but I'm having no luck finding it.

If it helps the file I'm working on looks like the following two lines repeated numerous times just with different values.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, NAME, VALUE) VALUES ('1','foo','all sorts of random stuff')
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, NAME, VALUE) VALUES ('2','bar','some other random stuff')
```

I want to to be able to jump my cursor to right after `'foo','` (ie my_constant_text).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `/constant_text/e` to jump to the end of the constant text, or `/constant_text/e+1` to jump just after it.

Comment: Apparently this is called a search offset, :help offset

Comment: you can also ://e+3, ://e-1, ://b+1 and varieties

Answer (score 2):

Things can be more versatile http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#{offset}

```
[...]  With "/" and "?" an
additional offset may be given.  There are two types of offsets: line offsets
and character offsets.  {the character offsets are not in Vi}

The offset gives the cursor position relative to the found match:
    [num]   [num] lines downwards, in column 1
    +[num]  [num] lines downwards, in column 1
    -[num]  [num] lines upwards, in column 1
    e[+num] [num] characters to the right of the end of the match
    e[-num] [num] characters to the left of the end of the match
    s[+num] [num] characters to the right of the start of the match
    s[-num] [num] characters to the left of the start of the match
    b[+num] [num] identical to s[+num] above (mnemonic: begin)
    b[-num] [num] identical to s[-num] above (mnemonic: begin)
    ;{pattern}  perform another search, see |//;|
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jan said, use the '/e' modifier. If it's more complicated then just a search string, there's always macros

```
qanf,q
```

to store the macro `nf,` (which would be your complicated stuff, not just `nf,`) in macro `a`, and then

```
@a
```

to call it.